# DynamicLink does not work when long tapping url and selecting "open in safari"

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I tested DynamicLink to see two case. I don't know, if this is an issue of IOS or DynamicLink.

App installed /
Open link in inbox email: https://xxx.app.goo.gl/abc
[image]
Case 1:

- Long tap to link and select "Open in Safari"
- Tap to open App on Safari => Don't open App. But open app store- all link after tap "Open in safari". All will not work. => Don't open app But open app store

Case 2:

- Long tap to link and select "Open in App" => open App
- If copy and paste to safari -> tap to open App => Open App
- all link after tap "Open in App". All will work ok. => open app

Comment: Please include a minimal code sample.

Comment: Have your tried the url in Notes ?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you see is expected.

When you

> Long tap on link and select "Open in Safari"

the Universal Links will be disabled on this iPhone for this domain. Firebase Dynamic Links are using iOS Universal Links under the hood. You will have to `Long tap on link and select "Open in App"` to re-enable the Universal Links. While Universal Links are disabled the Firebase Dynamic Links will not work correctly.

Comment: When Universal Links are disables you will see similar/broken experience in all Apps and browsers.

Comment: i got it. Thank you for support